# Display some grouped tableview sections according the state of the first section, how?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sections

I would a grouped tableview such that:

- when the only row of the first section is associated to a state, say A, I can see only this first section with, possibly, some text under it (in a footer for example);
- when this state changes, I would see other sections under the first;

How could I achieve this? Some code/link to obtain something similar?

Thanks,

Fran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, just add some if else logic in all your tableView Datasource and delegate methods.

For example like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!canUseInAppPurchase || isLoading) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (!canUseInAppPurchase || isLoading) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section == 0) {
        // this will be the restore purchases cell
        return 1;
    }
    return [self.products count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = ...
    NSString *cellText = nil;
    if (!canUseInAppPurchase) {
        cellText = @"Please activate inapp purchase";
    }
    else if (isLoading) {
        cellText = @"Loading...";
    }
    else {
        if (section == 0) {
            cellText = @"Restore purchases";
        }
        else {
            cellText = productName
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    return cell;
}
```

---

and if you want to add or remove the second section you could use a simply [tableView reloadData]; or this smoother variant:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
if (myStateBool) {
    // activated .. show section 1 and 2
    [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
else {
    // deactivated .. hide section 1 and 2
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

be careful, you have to change the data in your datasource first. And this code will add 2 sections. But you can adopt it to your needs easily.